# setcookie in php login script not working

Tags: php, cookies, setcookie

I have a login script in which i authenticate the user, and as soon as authentication is completed, i want to set cookies for him. but my script is executing perfectly till authentication, but it's not executing further after setcookie, may be it's not able to execute this function. Here is my code.

```
$validCredentials = checkCredentials($loginEmail, $loginPassword);
    if ($validCredentials === 1)
    {
        if(isset($_POST['rememberMe'])) 
        {
            $yearExpire = time() + 60*60*24*365; // 1 Year
            setcookie('rememberedUser', $loginEmail, $yearExpire);
            setcookie('loggedIn', $loginEmail, $yearExpire);
        }
        else  
        {
            if(isset($_COOKIE['rememberedUser'])) 
            {
                $pastExpire = time() - 100;
                setcookie('rememberedUser', '', $pastExpire);
            }
            $shortExpire = time() + 60*60*24;
            setcookie('loggedIn', $loginEmail, $shortExpire);
            die(msg(0,"Logged In !"));

        }
     }
```

Please tell me whats wrong in my code. Please help !!

Comment: Cookies are not secure, they can be set by user, also use `httponly` option unless you want some js to steal them

Answer (score 0):

you have written this line

```
die(msg(0,"Logged In !"));
```

and because of that it stops execution.

Comment: actually this is my own function, so i can't write anything after setcookie except the header ?? is that so

Comment: @RohitG `die` stops the execution of script.

Comment: i know that, i want it to stop, but this die() is not getting executed thats the problem, if i just comment the setcookie() then it executes fine, so whats the issue with this ?

Comment: @RohitG write `echo` before `setcookie` if it is `1` then it sets the cookie else not.eg `echo setcookie('loggedIn', $loginEmail, $shortExpire);`

Comment: i have modified the code to check what you have said, die(msg(0,setcookie('loggedIn', $loginEmail, $shortExpire))); but still i am not seeing anything, actually i am using ajax, and i am displaying all messages using my msg() function

Comment: I told you to do `echo setcookie('loggedIn', $loginEmail, $shortExpire);` not this `die(msg(0,setcookie('loggedIn', $loginEmail, $shortExpire)));`.

Comment: I have got the problem solved. Actually the issue was i had something like this in my script : <?php ---script1---  ?> <?php ---script2--- ?> which was causing the issue, I just changed it into a single PHP script <?php ---script1--- ---script2--- ?> which solved my problem, the code in ques is absolutely fine :)